# Next.js error with npm dependencies that import css

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a next.js project and want to use a component (from npm) which internally imports from typeface-montserrat.

Next.js gives an error:

```
<path>/node_modules/typeface-montserrate/index.css:2
@font-face {
^
Syntax Error: Invalid or unexpected token
```

My next.config.js is as follows

```
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')

module.exports = withCSS({
  cssLoaderOptions: {
    url: false
  }   
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please consider this configuration for your app in replacement to the current one `next.config.js`?

```
// next.config.js
const withCSS = require('@zeit/next-css')
module.exports = withCSS({
    cssModules: true
})
```

Comment: same error (I have both url-loader and file-loader installed).

Comment: I updated the answer, the case it self isn't clear on the cause of it, it might be. but it's possible that this is happending at the server mode.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work either. I got the same error and an additional one:

     [ error ] ./node_modules/typeface-montserrat/index.css  
     ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:4)
     You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
     (Source code omitted for this binary file)

Comment: I should have asked for this the first sec, what is the package name and the component you are using, I'll give it a shot on my machine.

Comment: its from a private npm repo. not publically available. Its a .ts component that imports typeface-montserrate

Comment: I have been looking around a solution for this, it seems hard to control that case since the font is imported internally in a package and the only way around this is to configure next to cover all the similar cases, possible solution: [click that one](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/38#issuecomment-152411328)

If it was something in your project itself, we could have used SASS configuration as a turn-around, sorry that I can't yet find a way out of this.

Comment: thanks for still trying. url-loader hasn't worked for me.

Comment: if I import typeface-montserrat directly in my app the error  goes away. So maybe the problem is with the fact the component I try to import is TS...
Tried using next-typescript but no luck

Comment: Oh, Still on it? did importing the font directly solved the problem?